# Regular expression to parse log file

Tags: python, regex

I have a SonicWall syslog file with this format:

```
<134>id=firewall sn=C0EAE470F7D0 time="2014-08-13 04:31:27" fw=10.2.3.4 pri=6 c=1024 m=537 msg="Connection Closed" n=301541 src=172.16.1.43:50581:X0 dst=172.16.1.1:192:X0 proto=udp/192 sent=46
```

I am trying to create a regular expression that will return a list of tuples that are split on the = sign.  If a value contains spaces, it will have double quotes.  I don't care if the values returned have the quotes returned or not, as long as the entire value with spaces is returned. For example, I want the time key to contain both the date & time.  Desired output:

```
("<134>id","firewall"), ("sn","C0EAE470F7D0"), ("time", '"2014-08-13 04:31:27"')
("fw","1.2.3.4"), ("pri","6"), ... ("msg", '"Connection Closed"'), ("n", "301541")
("src","172.16.1.43:50581:X0"), ... ("sent", "46")
```

This is what I have so far, but fails when a field with double quotes is encountered.  Also, the last field, "sent" in this case, is not returned.  I have experimented with the RE for a few hours trying various combinations, but just can't quite get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import re
fname = "syslog.log"
with open(fname) as fp: lines = fp.read().splitlines()
q = re.compile('(.*?)=(.*?)[\s"]',re.S|re.M)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    key_val = q.findall(line)
    print(key_val)
```

This is what this code returns:

```
[('<134>id', 'firewall'), ('sn', 'C0EAE470F7D0'), ('time', ''), 
('2014-08-13 04:31:27" fw', '10.2.3.4'), ('pri', '6'),
('c', '1024'), ('m', '537'), ('msg', ''), 
('Connection Closed" n', '301541'), ('src', '172.16.1.43:50581:X0'), 
('dst', '172.16.1.1:192:X0'), ('proto', 'udp/192')]
```

If this can't be accomplished with a regular expression, what would be the best way to achieve the desired result in Python 3.3?

Comment: As a side note, you really want to use raw strings for regexps (or escape your backslashes). Unless you know the list of string escapes by heart, and expect all of your readers to know them as well, don't rely on the fact that `\s` happens not to be one in current Python.

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `fp.read().splitlines()`; just do `list(fp)`. Or, even better, don't read it into a giant list at all; just do `for line in fp:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://regex101.com/r/wS5lX2/3

`(.+?)=("[^"]*"|\S*)\s*`

What it does

1. Match anything that's not an equals sign up to the equals sign
2. Match either

   1. Quotes around a string that does not contains quotes or
   2. A string without spaces
3. Match whitespace

If you additionally want to remove the quotes around the match, you can use this instead

http://regex101.com/r/wS5lX2/4

`(.+?)=(?:"(.*?)(?<!\\)"|(\S*))\s*`

It removes the double quote from the match string. The key will be group 1 and the value will be group 2 or 3. Additionally, it allows you to have backslash-escape quotes inside your quoted value.

Comment: Is last demo time is matched at index 2 whereas other are at index 3. Keep it consistent. By the way +1 for first demo that's what OP is looking for with double quotes.

Comment: Yes. I included that caveat in the answer. If you do not want that to be the case, use the first regex.

Comment: The RE for removing quotes: `re.compile('(.+?)=(?:"(.*?)(?<!\\)"|(\S*))\s*')`, under Python 3.3.5 returns `unbalanced parenthesis`.  But I don't see an imbalance.

Comment: @jftuga use a raw string. `re.compile(r'(.+?)=(?:"(.*?)(?<!\\)"|(\S*))\s*')`

Comment: @jftuga the problem is that python parses `\` as an escape character, then `re` parses every literal `\` as an escape character too, so when python reads the `(?<!\\)`, it parses it out to `(?<!\)`, then `re` reads `(?<!\)` and sees you escaping that close paren (e.g. `assert negative lookbehind of a literal `)` rather than closing the lookbehind). That imbalances your parentheses.

Comment: @Adam Smith: thank you for the explanation, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This will be easier if you grab all the tokens first, then split them.

```
import re
txt = """<134>id=firewall sn=C0EAE470F7D0 time="2014-08-13 04:31:27" fw=10.2.3.4 pri=6 c=1024 m=537 msg="Connection Closed" n=301541 src=172.16.1.43:50581:X0 dst=172.16.1.1:192:X0 proto=udp/192 sent=46"""

tokens = re.findall(r'''\S+=(?:"[^"]+?")|(?:'[^']+?')|\S+=\S+''', txt)

end_result = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.split('=')), tokens))
# output:
[('<134>id', 'firewall'), ('sn', 'C0EAE470F7D0'), ('time', '"2014-08-13 04:31:27"'), ('fw', '10.2.3.4'), ('pri', '6'), ('c', '1024'), ('m', '537'), ('msg', '"Connection Closed"'), ('n', '301541'), ('src', '172.16.1.43:50581:X0'), ('dst', '172.16.1.1:192:X0'), ('proto', 'udp/192'), ('sent', '46')]
```

explained:

```
re.compile('''
    \S+               # match one or more non-space characters
    =                 # match a literal equals
    (?:"[^"]+?")|     # match a double quotation and its contents OR
    (?:'[^']+?')      # match a single quotation and its contents
    |                 # OR
    \S+               # match one or more non-space characters
    =                 # match a literal equals
    \S+               # match one or more non-space characters
''', re.X)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -- jwz.

Whenever you're having problems writing a regexp, the first thing you should do is ask whether you really need a regexp. After all, if you can't figure out how to write it without using a graphical regexp explorer or getting someone else to help you, are you going to be able to debug it, expand it, or even read it in a couple months?

Your quoting rules seem to be the same as default CSV quoting rules. Which means you can let the `csv` module do the hard work for you, and then just split the key-value pairs, which is the easy part:

```
import csv
fname = "syslog.log"
with open(fname) as fp: 
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        key_val = [col.split('=', 1) for col in row]
        print(key_val)
```

Comment: This is nice, out of the box, thinking.  I like it -- really awesome.

Comment: @jftuga: The solution to problems with regexps is often "don't use regexps". When that doesn't work, the solution is tear your regexp into pieces, then fire up a really good graphical regexp explorer, then ask yourself, "Hold on, am I sure there's no way to do this without regexps?" Sometimes the answer is, "No, there's not" or "Yes, but it'll be way too verbose/ugly/slow", but often it's not.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the output you want (and also strips quotes):

```
line = """
<134>id=firewall sn=C0EAE470F7D0 time="2014-08-13 04:31:27" fw=10.2.3.4 pri=6 c=1024 m=537 msg="Connection Closed" n=301541 src=172.16.1.43:50581:X0 dst=172.16.1.1:192:X0 proto=udp/192 sent=46
"""

rx = r"""(?x)
    (\w+) =
    (?:
        " ([^"]*) "
        |
        (\S+)
    )
"""

parsed = [(id, a or b) for id, a, b in re.findall(rx, line)]
print parsed
```

I personally find dictionaries more suitable for this kind of data, that is:

```
parsed = {id: a or b for id, a, b in re.findall(rx, log)}
```